# combox selected index didnt work on picturebox

Tags: vb.net, combobox, visual-studio-2015, picturebox

Now what i was doing is when i click a button group box 1 and group box 2 will show out i want to select the combobox item than the picturebox item will load
and this can be used it multiple time like when button-5 clicked the combobox item name will change and the picture will change too.

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click

    GroupBox1.Show()
    GroupBox2.Show()

    comboboxselectdiffrent.Items.Add("pizza_ChickenSupreme")
    comboboxselectdiffrent.Items.Add("pizza_CockadoodleBacon")

    If comboboxselectdiffrent.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        PictureBox1.Image = PIZZA_HUT_SYSTEM_NEW_VER.My.Resources.Resources.pizza_ChickenSupreme
    ElseIf comboboxselectdiffrent.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
        PictureBox1.Image = PIZZA_HUT_SYSTEM_NEW_VER.My.Resources.Resources.pizza_CockadoodleBacon
    End If

End Sub
```

Can anyone tell me what i was do wrong? i have no idea why it wont work

Comment: What you're doing wrong depends on what you're trying to achieve.  If that `ComboBox` is empty before you click that `Button` then it's `SelectedIndex` will be -1 and adding those two items won't change that.  Why exactly would you be waiting until the `Button` is clicked to populate the `ComboBox` in the first place?  Surely the `ComboBox` should be populated at form load.

Comment: Debug `SelectedIndex `.

Comment: what i want to do is  try to reuse it.so when other button is click the item name in the combobox will change too. so i no need to create multiple combobox

Comment: first off, if you plan on using multiple images and items for the one combobox, use the `case statement` instead, also i have never used a picture like that to get a picture to load, i would normally do something like this `PictureBox1.ImageLocation = "Pictures/mypic.jpg"` and make sure you have `always copy content on`

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your code personality I would have the event trigger from the combobox click, that way it will save the user having to first click on the combo to select their pizza and then having to click on a button to load the picture & details.
 Nevertheless try this.

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ComboBox1.Items.Add("pizza_ChickenSupreme")
    ComboBox1.Items.Add("pizza_CockadoodleBacon")
    ComboBox1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    GroupBox1.Show()
    GroupBox2.Show()

    Select Case ComboBox1.SelectedItem
        Case Is = "pizza_ChickenSupreme"
            PictureBox1.ImageLocation = "Pictures/mypic.jpg"
        Case Is = "pizza_CockadoodleBacon"
            PictureBox1.ImageLocation = "Pictures/mypic1.jpg"

    End Select
    End Sub
    End Class
```

Using a custom Folder within the solution explorer will be better than using a setting resource. Create a folder and drag your pictures into it and change the name of the image location to suit your needs.

Also i think using the items name is better than the items index because what happens if someone reason that indexed item is to change from 1 to 5, you would have to recode it all, but by using the items name, it has more detail as to what to look for.

If you have any problems, leave a comment and I will do my best to help you out.
Happy Coding!